# Correct knife to use for portioning raw salmon?

Tags: fish, knife-skills, cutting

I recently bought a relatively large (~2lbs) filet of salmon. In order to portion it out I placed it skin side up on a cutting board and used a bread knife to essentially saw through the skin as it seemed pretty tough.

Is a bread knife the best option in this case? Is this something that should be done with a kitchen knife?

Comment: when you say portion the salmon, does it mean slicing like for sashimi? or just slicing into pieces, chunks or some relatively thin fillets but not as thin as sashimi?

Comment: @bonCodigo I mean into pieces/chunks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a bread knife would shred the skin and flesh.  I would place skin side down and, ideally, use a sharp slicing knife.  Sharp is the key.  I have also used a chef's knife and a fillet knife for this task.  The goal is to achieve a clean cut.

Comment: Agreed! Sharp and honed on a ceramic "steel" - send out your knives to be sharpened once a year, and "steel" (hone) regularly. A truly sharp knife at hand is like having kitchen superpowers.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal knife for this would be a fillet or boning knife, however if you don't have one a non-serrated knife would give you the best looking cut. There's no reason you cannot use a serrated knife, it's more cosmetic than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This may scandalize some cooks, but after years of struggling to cut through salmon skin, I have finally found a solution: use kitchen shears or scissors! They must be clean, and you'll have to wash them afterwards, but presto! Nice, neatly cut portions.

Comment: Are you cutting the whole filet with scissors (and if so, how do you avoid crushing the flesh), or just the tough skin?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).